# Как запустить GUI приложение из процесса-сервиса Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, service

Имеется Сервис, в котором на определенные запросы привязаны perl скрипты.
В некоторых скриптах запускаются GUI-утилиты.
При запуске скриптов с консоли все работает.
А вот если запускать эти скрипты как порожденные сервисом процессы, то графические приложения не запускаются.
То есть скрипты, судя по другим запросам, запускаются, а вот приложения прописанные в них - нет.

UPD: Сервис тормозит процесс perl скрипта по окончании таймаута - 1 минуты. И результат (код возврата) программы не удается узнать. Значит происходит что-то внутри процесса, что не дает ему выйти из петли.

Comment: В Windows есть такие понятия как *пользователи* и связанные с ними *сессии*, в которые первые выполняют вход. Службы же работают вне пользовательских сессий. В связи с этим вопрос: какому из залогиненных пользователей вы будете показывать окна приложений?

Comment: @Arhad: Хм. Например, всем интерактивным (то есть, у которых есть UI)?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/267838/2553424